# Image without content description using Compose

Tags: accessibility, android-jetpack-compose

In my app that only uses Jetpack Compose, I want show an image without a content description. The goal of this element is specifically to show how not to do it; I want TalkBack to pronounce it as 'unlabeled' and any other `AccessibilityService` to handle it like that service handles it. Therefore, the service needs to receive an `AccessibilityNodeInfo` node with as class name `"android.widget.ImageView"` and `contentDescription = null`

Google tried their very best to prevent developers from creating a bad experience for visually impaired and succeeded. An image without a content description is removed from the semantics tree and is not read out; an `AccessibilitityService` will not be aware of it:

```
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = null
)
```

Mimicking `Image()` and manually setting the Role to Image and not setting a description also removes it from the semantics tree:

```
Layout(
    {},
    modifier
        .semantics { this.role = Role.Image }
        .paint(painter)
) { _, constraints ->
    layout(constraints.minWidth, constraints.minHeight) {}
}
```

Also when I use an xml layout containing an ImageView without a content description, this does not show as an element to any accessibility services.

Compose implements `MyNodeProvider`, an `AccessibilityNodeProvider` which is Androids bridge between an accessibility service and an app. This is the class that populates the AccessibilityNodeInfo with a description or removes it from the tree. Because this is private, this cannot be altered.

Is it possible with Compose for an element to show up  as `"android.widget.ImageView"` with `contentDescription = null`?

Comment: Please be more elaborate. Provide a minimal-reproducible example, stating what you've tried and what you expect.

Comment: Elaborated further, hopefully this explains it better now.

Comment: Why not use the `AndroidView` Composable? That's not a problem at all -- super-easy, barely an inconvenience.

Comment: The interoperability of `AndroidView` is indeed pretty tight, but also this does not show up to talkback when the content description is missing

Answer (score 1):

If you want TalkBack to pronounce it as 'unlabeled', wouldn't setting the content description to 'unlabeled' be the way to go?

The question is not much clear, but if you want the content to be identified as nothing special or interactive with `TalkBack`, you could always set the `contentDescription` to `null`.

**BASED ON THE UPDATE**

You can simply use an `AndroidView` for this purpose

```
AndroidView(
  factory = {
    ImageView(...) // Populate it here
  }
)
```

This is in itself a `Composable` function so you can literally just swap out your `Image` Composable with this and it'll work.

Take [The Migration Codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-migration) to get full insights on API usage.

Comment: This was what I tried initially, but also this view is not visible to any accessibility service. Visually the image is there, but it's similar to setting `importantForAccessibility` to false unfortunately